# Preg_match using array?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-match

Correct usage is: `/,,([,]+)?|^,|,$|\b,\b|\s,/`

```
$comma[0] = '/,,([,]+)?/';  
            $comma[1] = '/^,/';     
            $comma[2] = '/,$/';
            $comma[3] = '/\b,\b/';  
            $comma[4] = '/\s,/';    

$analyst = preg_match($comma, $_POST['analyst']) 
    ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['analyst']) : NULL;
```

I am trying to detect commas from the users input, each regex is defined properly, but I do not understand why it isn't passing them into the if statement.

Edit:

if I change this:

```
$analyst = preg_match('test', $_POST['analyst']) 
    ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['analyst']) : NULL;
```

then it works, this makes no sense.

Comment: Try reading the documentation: [php.net/preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match)  -- of course it fails, it doesn't accept an array. Nothing odd or unexpected at all.

Comment: @Erik: People get confused, because `preg_replace` does.

Comment: No, Orbling, people just don't bother to look at basic documentation :(

Comment: A helpful answer would have been try using the pipe.

/,,([,]+)?|^,|,$|\b,\b|\s,|,/

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, what could you possibly be trying to match against that `str_pos( $_POST['analyst'], ',' )` wouldn't suffice?

Comment: I was trying to go for symmetry by reusing pieces of the array from a preg_replace elsewhere in the document where I am checking for things other than commas. But it is apparently not possible, you are right. That would work too/better.

Comment: @Ryan Valverde Ward: Thought it would be a `preg_replace` mix up.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Too bad the code isn't reusable between the two.

Comment: And originally I was looking for commas that occurred 1) At the beginning 2) At the end 3) With a word to the right 4) After another comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

preg_match() doesn't accept arrays as arguments, only strings.

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Well there you go. I just assumed it did. That is freaking weird. Thanks

Comment: Although it didn't solve my problem, it allowed me to learn how to use the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

[**preg_match**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) accept first parameter as string and you are passing an array.

Comment: Is there a technical reason for this? It seems like an oversight to me.

Comment: @Ryan: Take a look at posted link